# VBA Excel: Using/extracting data stored in CHM-file

Tags: vba, excel, chm

I am trying to extract data from a chm-helpfile using VBA. The CHM-file was downloaded and contains important data (such as the possible values for a dropdown-list) that I want to use as criteria for my analysis vba-tool. I would like to extract these tables with possible values and be able to follow the hyperlinks mentioned in the file.
After I manually unzip/extract the chm-file, I was able to use the htm-files, but it requires manual action, and I can't automate the unzip-action.

Is there any way to open the file to use this data?

Comment: Take a look here: https://file.org/extension/chm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  you have hh.exe installed you can decompile as follows:

**Arguments for hh.exe**

> -decompile folder chm

**Example Code**

Set your own path Information instead of D:\Project ...

```
 Public Sub HTMLHelp_Decompile()
 ' Arguments for hh.exe: -decompile folder chm
 On Error Resume Next
 Shell """hh.exe""" & _
       " -decompile D:\Project\Temp D:\Project\ddt.chm", vbNormalFocus
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Decompiling failed"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! In addition, of course you can replace  `" -decompile D:\Project\Temp D:\Project\ddt.chm"` with `" - decompile " & sDestPath & " " & sFilePath` where `sDestPath = "D:\Project\Temp": sFilePath = "D:\Project\ddt.chm"`

Comment: Welcome; just to complete the theme, you could compile again via `Shell` using `hhc.exe`, but indicating the html help project file (*.hhp) as sole argument. You'll find a helpful site for some related VBA at http://www.help-info.de